# File download in one click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to download an image file with a single click on a link or button that is drawn dynamically with the given content on the end users. The image is drawn by the HTML5 canvas.

I've tried this

```
function download() {
    var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    var img = document.getElementById('bg');
    var imgLogo = document.getElementById('logo');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 160, 600);
    ctx.drawImage(imgLogo, 30, 100, 86, 86);

    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

    var data = c.toDataURL('images/jpeg');;
    this.href = data;
}
```

The hidden button is:

```
<a id="downloadButton" class="btn btn-info" download="name.jpeg" style="display:none;">Hidden Button</a>
```

I need to download the image on another button click like the button bellow

```
<a id="anotherButton" class="btn btn-info">Download as image</a>
```

I've tried this code but it's not working

```
$('.download-img').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    download();

    return false;
});
```

For a single button this code is working fine with this code

```
downloadButton.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

But I need to click on "anotherButton" and make the same things happen. How is that possible?

Any help?

Comment: `$('#downloadButton').trigger('click')` comes to mind ?

Comment: Use [JQuery each method](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: I've tested this $('#downloadButton').trigger('click'); with no luck..

Answer (score 1):

Check my JS Fiddle- [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aynamohol/v1rm77zm/)

You will get an idea at least. You can use `html2canvas` to achieve this. You need to add the following scripts -

**Scripts library**

jQuery Library & html2canvas.js

**HTML**

```
<span id="contentbox">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="title ng-binding">Samrat Khan</div>
    </div>
</span>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>

<div id="outputaspng"></div>
```

**Scripts**

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#contentbox"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#outputaspng").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**html2canvas plugin has some limitation, don't avoid to read that**

Limitations
All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a proxy. Similarly, if you have other canvas elements on the page, which have been tainted with cross-origin content, they will become dirty and no longer readable by html2canvas.

The script doesn't render plugin content such as Flash or Java applets. It doesn't render iframe content either.